# Take screen shot in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, screenshot

How can I take a screen shot of the screen in XNA? Is it possible without `System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen` or Win32API? If it's not possible, Is there any way to draw a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to the game?

I want that it'll take a screen screenshot, then load the game in full screen mode, and then print the screenshot.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to take a screenshot of the system *before* the game loads, or take a screenshot of your game while it is running?

Comment: a screenshot of the system before the game loads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=537265&whichpage=1&#3469331

First create a ResolveTexture2D in your game's LoadContent method:

```
renderTargetTexture = new ResolveTexture2D(
        graphics.GraphicsDevice,
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight, 1,
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat);
```

Then resolve the back buffer in your Draw method after you draw your scene:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.ResolveBackBuffer(renderTargetTexture);
```

Finally, draw your captured back buffer using a spritebatch when your game is paused in your Draw method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(renderTargetTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
```

If you want the image to be grayscale, you'll need to write a pixel shader and load it with an effect file in your LoadContent, then set the effect before drawing the texture with the spritebatch.

Comment: It's not working, it's just shows the default XNA blue CornflowerBlue screen.

Comment: the problem is your end, that code is fine as far as I can see

Comment: How would I save this screenshot afterwards?