# xna 4 taking desktop screenshot

Tags: xna-4.0

Am currently working on a new application at work and am needing some help.

Basically I need to take real time screenshots of an application running on the users desktop(not my application) then warp the image using a shade and display the wrapped screenshot at 60 frames a second.

I have a windows form application that does this but I am getting 6 frames a second and when I scale this up to 1600x1600 it drops to 2fps.

So I thought that if I could do this in xna and move as much as possible to the GPU it would speed it up.

So I have googled and googled and cant find any information on how to get a screenshot of a running application in xna other than my xna application.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx) or additionaly the [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540.aspx) or [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29) to get the full desktop. Here are some links which can help you:

- [Capture screenshot of hidden desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375509/capture-screenshot-of-hidden-desktop)
- [Is there a way to take a screenshot of the user's Windows desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880878/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-users-windows-desktop)
- [C: take screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370702/c-take-screenshot)
- [What is the best way to take screenshots of a Window with C++ in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531684/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-a-window-with-c-in-windows)
- [Take screen shot in XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775196/take-screen-shot-in-xna)

I think there is no way to get a window screenshot of another application. You can use some pattern detection code to find out where a window is but I do not recommend this.

Comment: I can get the desktop using c# and GDI+ as a bitmap image but this is really slow and then I have no idea how to edit the image using a shader with out it being a texture.

Comment: GDI+ is slow, I not know any other way... To make texture out of a bitmap maybe this link will help: [How to get a Texture2D from Bitmap Variable?](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/3051/15056.aspx)